# move the selected items from checkedlistbox to listbox C#

Tags: c#, listbox, checkedlistbox

I'm trying to move the selected items from checkedlistbox to listbox.But I can't...

```
for (int x = 0; x<=checkedListBox1.Items.Count;x++ )
{
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(x))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: `checkedListBox1.Items[x]`

Comment: Thank for anwer but it don´t work. It don't have mistakes but it don't move the item :(

Comment: Arrays are zero based, so it should be `x < checkedListBox1.Items.Count`.  Get rid of the equal sign.

Comment: Now, it run! Thank you so much! But I dont undenstand why I have to put checkedListBox1.Items[x] and dont checkedListBox1.SelectItems

Comment: SelectedItem is for the item that is highlighted by the user.  It has nothing to do with your loop.

Comment: Ok thank you so much and how can I do from listbox to  checkedlistbox? That it's my bad solution for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
            {
                if (listBox1.GetSelected(x))
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[x] + "\r\n");

                }
            }

Comment: You seem obsessed with the "selected" part.  Get rid of your if-block since you're likely trying to move all the items back to the CheckedListBox.  While we're at it, get rid of that "\r\n" too.  You don't need line breaks in your items.

Comment: I don't want move all the items only select items.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will add selected items to `listBox1` and remove it from `checkedListBox1`, but `SelectedItems` will be one item each time because *Multi-selection is not supported on CheckedListBox* you can use `CheckedItems` instead of `SelectedItems` to select more than one item.

```
// Add Selected Items to ListBox
listBox1.Items.AddRange(checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<object>().ToArray());

// Remove from  CheckedListBox
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<object>().ToList())
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```